# Author less Books in Spring JPA many to many relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

Hi I am a newbie to Spring JPA. I am working on trivial Author and book example. A book can have many authors and An author can have many books. I am adding a book first and then trying to add author for it. I want to findout books which are not not asssigned any author. How do I do it

```
public class Book{
     public string Title;
     public Set<Author> Authors;
}

public class Author{
     public string Name;
     public Set<Book> Books;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

a Crudrepository method should do the job like below. Here I assumed the the primary id of Book as Integer `CrudRepository<Book, Integer>`

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Integer> {
...
    List<Book> findByBookAuthorsIsEmpty();
...
}
```